# When not immediately pending after sendTransaction

Tags: opensea, seaport

If I code sendTransaction with opensea Fulfillment data, the transaction goes well, but after sending the transaction, sometimes it is not immediately pending, it is pending later.

If I buy by hand instead of by code, even if I put less gas, I will naturally wait for the confirmation after being in the pending state immediately.

However, when I send sendTransaction to seaport with code, it is not pending immediately. Is there any solution? Thank you